# set variable to an instance of a function

Tags: javascript, function, instance

I wrote this javascript expecting the following outcome: "X:10"

```
function sprite() {
            var run= function() {
                window.setInterval(function(){
                    console.log("X:"+x.toString());
                },gameSpeed);
            };
            console.log("I'm Alive!");
            run();
    };
    var instance=new sprite();
    instance.x=10;
```

Instead, It throws this error: "ReferenceError: x is not defined"

What don't I understand here?

Comment: `sprite()` isn't returning anything

Comment: @StephenThomas Why do you think it needs to? They are using `new sprite()`

Comment: `instance` is going to be assigned an empty object

Comment: @StephenThomas No it's not, where do you see that happening? Do you know how the `new` operator works?

Comment: @stephenThomas that `new` keyword changes the behavior from what you are expecting.

Comment: x is really undefined.
you are trying to use x.toString() and you have never defined x anywhere.
instance.x is a property on the instance created you should access usually from inside an object function using this.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the self to hold reference to this; this way it will be captured next time setInterval fires

```
function sprite() {
        var self = this;
        var run= function() {
            window.setInterval(function(){
                console.log("X:"+self.x.toString());
            },gameSpeed);
        };
        console.log("I'm Alive!");
        run();
};
var instance=new sprite();
instance.x=10;
```

btw you also haven't defined gameSpeed anywhere

Comment: Works too , also made me understand the solution above better, Thanks!

Comment: also gameSpeed is defined elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

It'd be simpler (plus it'd actually work) to just pass in that value as a parameter:

```
function sprite(x) {
        var run= function() {
            window.setInterval(function(){
                console.log("X:"+x.toString());
            },gameSpeed);
        };
        console.log("I'm Alive!");
        run();
};
var instance = sprite(10);
```

Your code doesn't work because that's just not how JavaScript objects work, in more than one way. There's no implicit `this` in JavaScript, for one thing. Even if there were, the context of the function in the interval handler wouldn't be correct without some additional changes.

Now, if you really do want to be able to update the value logged, you would indeed have to use an object:

```
function sprite(x) {
        var run= function() {
            window.setInterval(function(){
                console.log("X:"+theSprite.x.toString());
            },gameSpeed);
        }, theSprite = this;

        theSprite.x = x;
        console.log("I'm Alive!");
        run();
};
var instance=new sprite(10);
// ... later on ...
instance.x = 20;
```

That stashes a reference to the constructed object in a local variable in the constructor function. That variable won't be changed subsequently, so the interval handler will continue to be able to use it to reference the sprite object and it's "x" property. Note that the `console.log()` call also changed to explicitly refer to the instance.

Comment: I'd love to do that , But I want to edit this value later and for the effect to show.

Comment: Maybe change the inner `instance` variable name to be something different, so it can't be confused with the outer `instance`. I was confused until I barely saw the `, instance = this;`

Comment: @Pointy works! Side question , do I need a more solid understanding of JS and the "this" keyword if I can't solve this issue?

Comment: @user29619 yes it's pretty important to understand how `this` works in JavaScript - it's quite a bit different from other languages that *look* similar. There are great questions about it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your function/object trial.

Even if you returned you are not defining X before using it.

if you want to edit it later do like this(not changing your code too much):

```
var sprite = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.x = 0;
    self.run = (function(){
        window.setInterval(function(){
            console.log("X:" + self.x.toString());
        }, gameSpeed); //assuming gameSpeed ai available in this scope...
    }());
    console.log('I AM ALIVE MUAHAHAHAH!');
};

var instance = new sprite();
instance.x = 10;
```

check: http://jsbin.com/ducap/1/edit

Comment: like my suggestion,
it has nothing to do with returning anything. just the fact that he did not defined x anywhere and he probably meant to access the x property of the instance, your solution should work

Comment: yep we did basically the same thing.
Differ on the pattern used, but the doubt is very basic and was wrong in the fundamental part.
Hope we can help.